# ¿Como enviar propiedades a un callback cuando se lanza el @click en lit-element?

Tags: dom, polymer, web-components

Estoy tratando de que cuando se lance el evento de click en un componente en lit-element se ejecute un callback y este pueda recibir un valor específico:

```
this.list.map(item => html`
  <button @click=${this._handleClick}></button>
`)

_handleClick(e){
console.log(item);
}
```

¿Como se puede obtener **item** en el scope del callback _handleClick?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
this.list.map((item) => html`
  <button @click=${() => this._handleItemClick(item)}></button>
`)

_handleItemClick(item) {
  console.log(item);
}
```